# How to copy text in the Windows command line 'cmd'?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-vista

Is there any way to copy text that's shown in the Command Prompt window `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` to the clipboard?

Comment: nelaar's answer is the best way.

Comment: @barlop this is weird, it isn't working for me. take a look at the comments below it

Comment: ok I see nelaar got his instructions completely wrong, see my response below it with correct ones.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Right click on the title bar and go to edit menu
>    All the options you need are there (copy, paste, select)

or To change the option to allow quick editing

> Right click on the title bar and go to properties > quickedit mode enable.
>    Now you don't need to go through the edit menu to select or copy or paste.
>
> > Enter short cut to copy
> >     Right click short cut to paste
> >     Left click drag to select text.

Every thing is put into a the system clip board so crtl + v will work in to other applications like notepad.

[image: QuickEditMode]

Comment: This is weird, I've got quickedit mode enabled but Ctrl+V isn't working. Netiehr is the press of the enter key doing paste..

Comment: @pacerier well, I see he got it wrong,  but he's right about quickedit mode. Quickedit mode is great i'd use it always. Go into quickedit mode, then the way you copy is you highlight what you want to copy, it gets highlighted in a block. Then hit ENTER, then it unhighlights, and what you highlighted went into the clipboard.  In order  to paste, you right click.

Comment: @barlop cool it's working thx =)

Comment: @nelaar your answer is partly right and with wrong instructions, you shoudl clear it up. I upvoted it before I saw your instructions were completely off and now I can't remove that upvote I gave you. your answer is currently mostly a shambles. you should fix your answer. I suggest using <s> and </s>  to strikethrough parts and write the correct one. At least the comments to this answer explain everything.

Comment: @barlop. You guys were correct. I should have done a better job explaining, thanks for the input. I hope that my changes better explain what needs to happen and how it works. Just have to wait for it get reviewed before it shows up.

Comment: -1 for not editing the answer to correct/clarify it.

Answer (score 12):

You need to right click and select **Mark**

You can then highlight the rectangle of text you want to copy.

Then hit `Return` to copy it into the clipboard.

Comment: Right click, select Mark. Mouse cursor to beginning, left-click and drag to highlight text. Release left mouse button and then left-click in highlighted area. Highlight going away is text being saved to clipboard. It's all mousework.

Answer (score 6):

1. Enter marking mode: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd>
   <sup>(yes, these are just the hotkeys for the process described in [nelaar's answer](https://superuser.com/a/295372/36744))</sup>.
2. Move the cursor with the arrow keys to the start of your selection (the selection is rectangular).
3. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select text while using the arrow keys to expand your selection.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy the selection to the clipboard.

Comment: @:Oliver Good stuff =)

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click and and select mark
   [image: mark]
2. Block the text that you want to copy (by hold Shift key + bottom , top, right, or left)
   [image: block the text]
3. Press "ENTER"
4. Paste it into notepad or other (MS. Word, Etc.).

Comment: Yes, that's already been answered. A year ago.

Comment: that is clearly written and also in quickedit mode you can just drag across the screen with your mouse

Answer (score 0):

I got Windows 10 Home. When I want to repeat (copy) a command or part of if I've written previously I just keep pressed the mouse left button to select the are I want to copy, release the button, place the cursor where I want to copy it and tap twice the mouse right botton and that's all, it is copied. That's on cmd.

Comment: You dug out a question for Windows Vista. Please verify tags before answering.