# How to copy the command prompt commands to a text editor?

Tags: command-line, notepad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy text in the Windows command line 'cmd'?](https://superuser.com/questions/295370/how-to-copy-text-in-the-windows-command-line-cmd)

How to copy the commands typed in the command prompt onto a text editor or Word?

As <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work in the command prompt, how else can one achieve that?

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Just launch the command prompt like you usually launch it and do the work you like to do.

1. Now Right click anywhere in command line window and select the `Mark` option.
2. Now use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> key to select the desired text.

   **Note:** When you active the **Mark**, the cursor will probably go to the top of the window. Now you can move it using the arrow keys.
3. After selecting the desired text, hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to copy it to clipboard and paste it on notepad.