# how to right click a window title bar from a surface 3 tablet?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, gui, tablet, right-click

how do I right [click](https://superuser.com/q/295370/55747) the title bar for a window on a surface 3 tablet?  There's no mouse, but there is a keyboard with mousepad.

Comment: The mousepad probably has a right click button on the bottom right hand side of it. Alternatively using the touch screen and doing a "touch and hold" on the title bar should bring up the context menu.

Comment: The "touch and hold" worked fine.  thx.