# How to highlight or select text in a console shell? (CLI)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, gui, tablet, microsoft-surface-3

For a regular surface 3 tablet, how do I highlight or select text in the console so that it's copied to the clipboard?

With a mouse it's easy enough.  However, no mouse for a tablet.

I [enabled](https://superuser.com/q/1308942/55747) the "quick edit" on the console window so this should be do-able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy & paste using `right-click` in most shells in Windows 10. A `press-and-hold` is `right-click` on Surface-devices.

This means you can highlight the desired text by simply `dragging` over it with your finger. Then `press-and-hold` the highlighted text. Afterwards you can paste your copied text by `press-and-holding` again.

I just tested this in a regular CMD and PowerShell terminal on my Surface Pro 4, using Windows 10.